# How to resize width of an image in a listview in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` that contains `Image` as the Items. I want the width of each image to follow the width of the ListView whenever I resize the Grid that contains it.

```xml
<!--Playlists-->
<Grid Column="0">
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              ... >

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <!--Images-->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:PlaylistModel}">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                           Stretch="Uniform">
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</Grid>

<GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" />
```

Source: http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/2016/03/21/c-how-to-make-a-panel-within-a-datatemplate-fill-the-entire-width-of-a-listview-or-itenscontrol-derivative/

[This is what happens](https://chito.ge/7gjbJNK.gif)

As seen here, the width of the image doesn't resize at all. The image size just stays the same even when the size of the ListView changes. However, if I set the width of the `Grid` inside of `DataTemplate` then the Image would actually follow that width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a mistake to use `ListView`. Changing everything to a `ListBox` fixed it for me.

Leaving this here if someone encounters the same problem.

```xml
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:PlaylistModel}">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                       Stretch="Uniform" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```